# %% Cell magic tag not working in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm new to Jupyter notebook and I'm trying to set one up with Python and R, using rpy2. I have the line

```
%%R -i df
```

which gives me the error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

However when I use just one %, such as

```
%R require(ggplot2)
```

this works fine. How can I fix this issue? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: `%` prefix is for a line magic, whereas `%%` prefix is for a cell magic

Comment: Do you know why the cell magic prefix gives a syntax error and the line magic prefix does not? I have rpy2.ipython loaded.

Comment: yes, a cell magic must be the only instruction on that line, and the body of the cell must not be empty. (see answer below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%` prefix is for a line magic, whereas `%%` prefix is for a cell magic.

```
%%R    # <-- must be the only instruction on this line
{body of cell in R code}
```

whereas:

```
%R {one line of R code}
```

I don't have R installed, but I think you may have wanted to call a bash command on R; in that case, use `!` to call the command:

```
!R -i df
```

for instance, if I type `!python -i`, I get info about my current python environment:

```
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Great, glad I could be of help.

Comment: It really important info, Event a comment line before `%%sql` gives error

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I run into the same problem today. Reblochon Masque's answer no longer applies as of today. `%%R -i df` in the middle of a cell throws `invalid syntax`. Also `!R -i df` throws `WARNING: unknown option '-i' ARGUMENT 'df' __ignored__`.

Here is what I need to do to cell magic `R` to work:

1. follow [this instruction](https://answers.dataiku.com/14/in-an-r-notebook-i-have-the-error-cell-magic-r-not-found) to install `R` packages `RJSONIO` and `httr` (package name is indeed lowercase) and `Python` package `rpy2`. No further configuration is needed.
2. put just one line `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` in a cell to invoke `rpy2`.
3. `%%R` has to be at the very beginning of a cell, so I put this line in the next cell.
4. the body of cell cannot be empty after `%%R`.
5. `%%R -i df` does work as intended.